# plank has duplicate icons for added launchers in LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, launcher, icons, lxde, plank

I am on Lubuntu and just installed plank for a dock.  I have figured out how to remove launchers by dragging and dropping and the go [poof] in a cloud, and I figured out how to add by right clicking and selecting "keep in dock"

the problem is, certain apps have duplicate icons.  that is to say, after I added chrome, it stays in the dock when I close it, but then when I click it to open it, another icon for chrome appears at the bottom.  So, one chrome icon is the app that is running, highlighted with a blue dot underneath, and another is the one that is the app launcher.

also, weirdly, the icon that is representing the active window has a different icon.  the one that is the launcher is the nice, shiny square icon similar to Moku or Faenza.  the icon that is representing the active app is low res, blurry, and just the standard chrome circle.

the double icon problem also happens for firefox, which was already in the dock.  Firefox thankfully does not have the ugly icon problem though.  that is unique to chrome.

other launchers such as the PCManFM one doesn't duplicate, and neither does my terminal launcher.

any help?  thanks!

Comment: this should be gone by now, it's been fixed in Chrome very recently

Answer (score 2):

These answers helped me:
http://elementaryos.org/answers/plank-shows-duplicate-icons-for-some-apps-when-you-open-them

Namely, copying `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` to `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome-stable.desktop` and replacing `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` with `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome` in both files.

Comment: life saver man, works on unity also :-D

Comment: The same happens when you install emacs from the kellyk's ppa, just go to `/usr/share/applications/emacs27.desktop` and change the icon and exec entry to just say emacs instead of emacs27.